# sql замена куска текста

Tags: sql

Подскажите запрос. Имеем в базе строки вида:

```
... src="https://i025.domen.rr/0711/ba/7d4125179384.jpg" height= ...
... src="https://y88e.domen.rr/09/fgf7f77fdd" height= ...
... src="https://6tee.domen.rr/09eerre/u77474u4u4.png" height= ...
```

и т.д. domen.rr всегда неизменен.
Нужно заменить все что в "" на "https://svoi.cc"
на выходе что бы получилось:

```
... src="https://svoi.cc" height= ...
... src="https://svoi.cc" height= ...
... src="https://svoi.cc" height= ...
```

и т.д.

Comment: Именно `src="https://svoi.cc"`, а не `src="https://svoi.cc/0711/ba/7d4125179384.jpg"`?

Comment: Да. Именно так. замена домена с удаление всего что после слэша. Замена просто домена это решаемо. Возможно что то типа между src= и height= любое количество символов, и условие содержащих domen.rr (что бы не заменил другие ссылки)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение сильно зависит от диалекта самой СУБД, которую вы не указали.

Вариант 1.

Скорее всего одним UPDATE не получится, придётся писать хранимую процедуру.

1. Найти в строке положение `src="`
2. Найти в строке положение `"`, которое после найденной ранее позиции + 5 (длина первой подстроки). Функции поиска подстроки как правило принимают третий необязательный параметр, который указывает стартовую позицию поиска.
3. Вырезать строку между ними. Если она `like 'https://%domen.rr%`, то собрать новую строку из того что в оригинальной до первой позиции, `'src="https://svoi.cc'` и того что после второй.

Вариант 2.

Работает только если СУБД поддерживает замену регулярными выражениями.

Найти в строке `src="https://([^"/]*\.)?domen.rr/[^"]*"` и заменить на `src="https://svoi.cc"`

Пояснения к регулярке:

- `[^"/]*\.` — что угодно кроме кавычки и слэша любое количество раз, и точка в конце. Находит поддомен
- `[^"]*` — что угодно кроме кавычки любое количество раз. Находит текст ссылки до конца.